# Elasticsearch: How to query using partial phrases in quotation marks

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to implement a search behavior that supports partial phrases. A possible search input could look like this:

> example "hello world" elasticsearch

Now I want to get all documents, that contain the words `example` and `elasticsearch` as well as the phrase `hello world`.

As this is a very typical use case for searches I was surprised that I couldn't find much on this topic.

I tried several approaches (pattern tokenizer, pattern capture filter) but none of them worked properly. Before I start to implement a custom approach to build a complex query definition programmatically, is there a recommended way to achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) will do just this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "example \"hello world\" elasticsearch",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: quite obvious if you read the documentation properly ;)
thank you very much!